# Angular UI-Layout overlaps with navbar

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am recently trying Angular UI Layout (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-layout) which is pretty straightforward to use. However, I found the UI layout always overlaps with navbar of Bootstrap.

YOu can take a look at it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/r5veawwbgz98bZjLdr1B

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="x">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <title>UI.Layout Issue</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgithub.com/angular-ui/ui-layout/v1.0.5/ui-layout.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i><span>Website</span></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Menu2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">Menu3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">Menu4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
     </nav>

    <div ui-layout  style="position:relative; height:500px">
      <div ui-layout-container style="border-style: solid;"><h1>top</h1></div>

      <div ui-layout-container> 
        <div ui-layout="{flow : 'column'}" >
          <div ui-layout-container style="border-style: solid;" ><h1>left</h1></div>
          <div ui-layout-container style="border-style: solid;"  ><h1>right</h1></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div ui-layout-container style="border-style: solid;"><h1>bottom</h1></div>
    </div>

  <!-- Le javascript -->
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/angular-ui/ui-layout/v1.0.5/ui-layout.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('x', ['ui.layout']);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

A further investigation shows it is caused by the absolute positioning of UI layout. If I add a sytle:

```
<div ui-layout  style="position:relative; height:500px">.
```

UI layout will not overlap with navbar anymore.

However, another issue arises, if the screen size changes, I have to manually change the height property of style.

So I am wondering whether there is any easy way to handle this.

Thanks
Derek

Comment: This is also a problem even if you use ui-router to put ui-layouts in templates.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's too late, but i have the same problem and this is my solution : 
simply add a fake div with size and max-size with value of your navbar's height to your ui-layout and make your navbar fix on top !

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

  <div ui-layout>
<div ui-layout-container size="40px" max-size="40px" style="border-style: solid;">
  <h1>fake</h1></div>
<div ui-layout-container style="border-style: solid;">
  <h1>top</h1></div>

<div ui-layout-container>
  <div ui-layout="{flow : 'column'}">
    <div ui-layout-container style="border-style: solid;">
      <h1>left</h1></div>
    <div ui-layout-container style="border-style: solid;">
      <h1>right</h1></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div ui-layout-container style="border-style: solid;">
  <h1>bottom</h1></div>
```

this is [your plunker updated](http://plnkr.co/edit/AxHNPlAZ31xghidiybmN?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap your UI-Layout to container with styles to prevent overlap:

```
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nRW2qbiwadyO1ICdgbQq

Comment: that is a hack, not the way I want. For example, if you put some contents under the UI-Layout, you have to manually change the style. See an example here:http://plnkr.co/edit/0cKLghOFVAXzk76ccGKD 
I put " <div>Not working fluently . </div>" after the UI-layout and these contents overlap with UI-layout contents.